# Filtering tweets using the Premium Twitter API vs the Standard API

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitterapi-python

In the Standard Twitter API it is possible to filter the tweets so that only the most popular ones are shown using this parameter in the Twitter API request:

```
result_type: 'popular'
```

However, in the Premium Twitter API this operator is missing.

Do you know how I can get that same filter using the `fullarchive` Premium Twitter API endpoint?

I know I could look at every tweet's number of retweets, but I'm looking for a more automatic solution to reduce the number of requests that I have to make.

I'm using it in a Node.Js app, so as there's no up-to-date Twitter module I'm using the direct REST request endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, the only thing you can do here is to do some manual checks of your own to establish "popularity" - there is no operator combination that you can pass in to premium search that would give back something similar to what was available in the legacy standard search.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy. Don't you think this is a bit strange? I mean why would they not include this parameter into their premium search product?